# How to update the margin or padding for the xAxis in nvd3 chart?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, charts, nvd3.js

**Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ymrqIOGTBqF6TVMTvC4T?p=preview**

^ In my example above the xAxis time data is too close to the bottom of the chart, I've been playing with the CSS, but haven't had any luck in making anything move. Is there another way to give at least even a 5 pixel space padding/margin between the xAxis time data and the chart?

[image]

What I've tried:

```
#chart {
  height: 400px;
}

.nv-axisMaxMin,
.nv-axisMaxMin-x,
.nv-axisMin-x {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Even this doesn't work:

```
svg text {
    font: 400 12px Arial;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: absolute; // Just move! :'(
    top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the css will not work, since the the `x` and `y` value attributes of the text are dynamically generated.

Here is a cheeky way of doing,

```
// FOR THE REGULAR VALUES
d3.selectAll('.nv-x.nv-axis > .nv-wrap.nv-axis > g > g.tick > text').each(function(d,i){
    d3.select(this).attr('dy', '2em');
});

// For the MIN and MAX values    
d3.selectAll('.nv-x.nv-axis > .nv-wrap.nv-axis > .nv-axisMaxMin > text').each(function(d,i){
    d3.select(this).attr('dy', '2em');
})
```

Hope it helps.